# Is there a terminology to denote a topological vector space that admits an inner product?

Tags: terminology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(V,\tau)$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{K}$.

If there is a norm $||\cdot||$ on $V$ such that the metric topology induced by $||\cdot||$ is $\tau$, then we call $V$ is **normable**.

Likewise, if there is an inner product on $V$ such that the metric topology induced by the inner product is $\tau$, what is $V$ called in this case? Inner productable sounds weird..